# sed: replacing entries in the /etc/fstab

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression, fstab

I'm in the process of hardening some of our systems. As part of that hardening process, I need to update a few entries in the /etc/fstab to limit the capabilities of some of the various partitions.

With that said, I would like be able to use a sed in-line replace to update the rows. Below is a snippet from the current /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Wed Feb 21 09:37:23 2018
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv_home /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
```

After the sed command is run I would like the file to look like the following:

```
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Wed Feb 21 09:37:23 2018
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv_home /home                   ext4    defaults,nodev        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
```

Basically, I need to add "nodev" to all the rows that are ext[2-4], that aren't the root partition.

The sed command that I put together comes close to doing this, but for whatever reason, I can't get the regex to not match the "/" partition, so it always updates that row also.

```
sed '/^[^#].*ext[2-4]/s/defaults/defaults,nodev/g' /etc/fstab
```

I would like to key off of the "/" surrounded by spaces, not the vg1-lv_root. The following works, but I don't like the solution because it's clunky:

```
sed '/^[^#].*ext[2-4]/s/defaults/defaults,nodev/g' /etc/fstab | sed '/^[^#].*root.*ext[2-4]/s/defaults,nodev/defaults/' > /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Is this on a Linux machine? Can we assume GNU tools?

Answer (score 5):

You could use `awk` to add the logic to add the string and `column` to reformat the final output file. Assuming you have write permissions to the `/etc/` and `/tmp/` folders

```
tempfile=$(mktemp /tmp/tmpfile.XXXXXXXX)
```

This would create the temporary file in the `/tmp/` path in which you can write the `awk` output to and re-direct that back to the original file

```
awk '$3 ~ "ext[2-4]"{ $4=$4",nodev" }1 ' /etc/fstab | column -t > "$tempfile" && mv -- "$tempfile" /etc/fstab
```

The `column -t` part is just redundant and needed to look the output file more readable, rather to make it disordered and clunky.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  That's a cool way of solving the problem.

Comment: I undeleted this since it is a good and helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks @terdon, I saw OP's comment of having to use `sed` and without using temporary file

Comment: Well, @Jason (and Inian) if you have access to a newish GNU awk (which you do if you're on Linux), you can do `gawk -iinplace '$3 ~ "ext[2-4]"{ $4=$4",nodev" }1 ' OFS="\t" /etc/fstab`. Not as pretty as `column`, but it uses a tab for output which looks cleaner than a space and it will edit in place.

Comment: You can avoid the tempfile by using `sponge`, i.e. `awk ... | column ... | sponge /etc/fstab`. Sponge will wait until it's read the entirety of stdin ("soaking it up") before writing to the file specified.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simpler `sed` approach:

```
$ sed -E 's|(\s/\S+\s+ext[2-4]\s+defaults)|\1,nodev|' fstab 
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Wed Feb 21 09:37:23 2018
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv_home /home                   ext4    defaults,nodev        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
```

The trick is to look for whitespace followed by a `/` and one or more non-whitespace characters (`\s/\S+`), then `ext[2-4]` but only if preceded by whitespace (`\s+ext[2-4]`), more whitespace and `defaults`. That should only match the cases you are interested in. So if it does match, replace the entire match with itself plus `nodev`: `\1,nodev`.

I am not sure how portable this is, however. The `-E` for extended regular expressions is supported by many `sed` implementations, but it isn't POSIX. For a more portable approach, you can try the same idea in Perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's|(\s/\S+\s+ext[2-4]\s+defaults)|\1,nodev|' fstab 
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Wed Feb 21 09:37:23 2018
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv_home /home                   ext4    defaults,nodev        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
```

In both cases, to edit the file in place, use `-i`:

```
perl -i -pe 's|(\s/\S+\s+ext[2-4]\s+defaults)|\1,nodev|' fstab 
sed -E 's|(\s/\S+\s+ext[2-4]\s+defaults)|\1,nodev|' fstab
```

Or, for BSD or OSX `sed`:

```
sed -i '' -E 's|(\s/\S+\s+ext[2-4]\s+defaults)|\1,nodev|' fstab
```

Note that the above assume that the `defaults` option will either be the only one or, at least, the last one. They will fail if you have something like `nodev,defaults` for example.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, ten minutes after posting the question, I was finally able to get it to do what I want with the following:

```
sed -r '/^[^#].*[ \t]+\/[^[:space:]].*ext[2-4]/s/defaults/defaults,nodev/g' /etc/fstab
```

If someone has a cleaner or more foolproof answer, I'd love to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the main question was, "what am I doing wrong with my regular expression?".  Sorry, I probably should have been more clear in my original post.  I would prefer to not create temporary files if I can solve the problem with a sed one-liner.

Comment: Why are you assuming `\t`? As far as I know, all `fstab` needs is whitespace so there's no reason you will always have a tab there.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding matches are difficult to maintain. It's safer to only match the partition you want. And, for only matching one line, the trailing 'g' isn't necessary.

```
sed -r 's#(/home\s.*defaults)\s#\1,nodev #' /etc/fstab
```